# Why is my $HOME variable set to C:\Windows\system32 when I run vim as a different user and what can I do about it?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows

I've created another domain user in Windows and I'm trying to run gvim from it.

I've created a `%USERPROFILE%\_vimrc` but when I start gvim and check `:echo $HOME` it's set to `C:\Windows\system32`.

I'd like to have different domain users with different `_vimrc` for different purposes, but if they all end up in `C:\Windows\system32` I'll have to load them up individually, and that's useless.

So how do I set the `$HOME` directory to `%USERPROFILE%` even though I've started it using a different account?

Comment: Can you create a system environment variable `$HOME`/ `%HOME%` for those new users? If this variable is not available, Vim guesses and constructs it from `$HOMEDRIVE` and `$HOMEPATH` which may be wrong in your case

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt do you mean `$ENV:HOME` in Powershell?

Comment: I do not know Powershell, so not sure if this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined that I was missing about 5 user Environment variable for vim in that user's user profile:

- `MYVIMRC` - Should be a path that points to the `_vimrc` file.
- `VIM` - A path that points to the installed vim directory.
- `VIMRUNTIME` - A path that points to the installed vim directory.
- `HOMEPATH` - points to `\Users\<username>`
- `HOMEDRIVE` - points to drive with user profiles `C:`

I had to login as the user to do this.

Comment: If HOME is set, vim should set those automatically i believe

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You are correct as usual sir!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571200/18149